How to run Timer in React Native with Expo, when close app
I have a timer, that has 2 states. First state time is running out (for instance 3min. goes to 0,countdown) and the second state which starts when first timer (countdown) is equal to 0.
When i fold the app, timer works correct, but when i close it through "the last opened app" button (on android 1st left down button) and open app again then timer is reset.
Is there a way how can i run a timer even when i close it. I tryed AppState from React Native but it doesn't watch when you close the app completely, only when you fold it.
For timer i use library -
import { useStopwatch, useTimer} from 'react-timer-hook';

const stopwatchOffset = new Date(); 
  stopwatchOffset.setSeconds(stopwatchOffset.getSeconds() + 120);

  const {
    seconds: stopwatchSeconds,
    minutes: stopwatchMinutes,
    hours: stopwatchHours,
    start: startStopwatch,
    reset: resetStopwatch,
    totalSeconds,
    isRunning: stopwatchRunning,
  } = useStopwatch({ autoStart: false, offsetTimestamp: stopwatchOffset});

  const expiryTimestamp = new Date();
  expiryTimestamp.setSeconds(expiryTimestamp.getSeconds() + 120); // 2 минуты

  const {
    seconds: timerSeconds,
    minutes: timerMinutes,
    hours: timerHours,
    start: startTimer,
    isRunning: timerRunning,
    restart: timerRestart,
  } = useTimer({
    expiryTimestamp,
    autoStart: false,
    onExpire: () => {
      schedulePushNotification('О нет! Начался нормальный интервал!', 'Не забудь прокатетеризироваться!');
      setInitialStrip(0); // обнуляем секундные полоски
      if(partTime.firstPartTime){
        setPartTime({firstPartTime: true ,secondPartTime: true, thirdPartTime: false}); // делаем Нормальный интервал активным, там время идет на возрастание
      }
      setStartFromСountdown(false);
      startStopwatch();
    }
  });


Now im trying to use import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
